# How to draw the corresponding part of the projection mesh of this surface

Tags: plotting

I want to divide a surface `f[x_, y_] := (1.4025 - (-0.2 + x)^2 - (-0.2 + y)^2)^0.5 + 0.15` into meshes corresponding to the region x0y

```
f[x_, y_] := (1.4025 - (-0.2 + x)^2 - (-0.2 + y)^2)^0.5 + 0.15;
X[x_, y_] := Evaluate@D[f[x, y], x]
Y[x_, y_] := Evaluate@D[f[x, y], y]
GetRegion[n_, 
  m_] := {TwoD$Points = Outer[List, #, #] &@Subdivide[0, 1, n]; 
   TwoD$Points = (Flatten[#, 1][[{1, 2, 4, 3}]] & /@ 
      Flatten[Partition[TwoD$Points, {2, 2}, 1], 1]);
   TwoD$Points[[m]]} // Flatten[#, 1] &
GetLine[n_, 
  m_] := {TwoD$Points = Outer[List, #, #] &@Subdivide[0, 1, n]; 
   TwoD$Points = (Flatten[#, 1][[{1, 2, 4, 3}]] & /@ 
      Flatten[Partition[TwoD$Points, {2, 2}, 1], 1]);
   ThreeD$Points = Map[Flatten[{#, 0}] &, TwoD$Points, {2}][[m]]; 
   List[ThreeD$Points, 
     Apply[{#1, #2, f[#1, #2]} &, ThreeD$Points, 2]] // Transpose} // 
  Flatten[#, 1] &
NormalLine[n_, 
  m_] := {TwoD$Points = Outer[List, #, #] &@Subdivide[0, 1, n]; 
   TwoD$Points = (Flatten[#, 1][[{1, 2, 4, 3}]] & /@ 
      Flatten[Partition[TwoD$Points, {2, 2}, 1], 1]);
   ThreeD$Points = Map[Flatten[{#, 0}] &, TwoD$Points, {2}][[m]]; 
   List[ThreeD$Points, 
     Apply[{#1, #2, f[#1, #2]} &, ThreeD$Points, 2]] // Transpose} // 
  Flatten[#, 1] &


Manipulate[region = GetRegion[n, m]; 
 Show[Plot3D[{f[x, y], 0}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &}, Mesh -> n - 1, 
   MeshShading -> 
    ReplacePart[
     ConstantArray[Automatic, {n, n}], {Mod[m, n, 1], Ceiling[m/n]} ->
       Red], PlotRange -> {{0, 1.6}, {-0.2, 1.4}, {0, 1.6}}, 
   BoxRatios -> Automatic], 
  Plot3D[X[(region[[1, 1]] + region[[3, 1]])/
       2, (region[[1, 2]] + region[[2, 2]])/
       2] (x - (region[[1, 1]] + region[[3, 1]])/2) + 
    Y[(region[[1, 1]] + region[[3, 1]])/
       2, (region[[1, 2]] + region[[2, 2]])/
       2] (y - (region[[1, 2]] + region[[2, 2]])/2) + 
    f[(region[[1, 1]] + region[[3, 1]])/
      2, (region[[1, 2]] + region[[2, 2]])/2], {x, region[[1, 1]], 
    region[[3, 1]]}, {y, region[[1, 2]], region[[2, 2]]}, 
   Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Opacity[0.6]}], 
  Graphics3D[{Thick, Dashed, Pink, Line@GetLine[n, m]}]], {{n, 4, 
   "Divide quantity"}, 3, 30, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Open"}, {{m, 1, "Division number of sub region j"}, 
  1, n^2, 1, Appearance -> "Open"}]
```

But I can't match the jth red mesh in xoy with the surface `f[x_, y_] := (1.4025 - (-0.2 + x)^2 - (-0.2 + y)^2)^0.5 + 0.15`.What should I do to make the corresponding part of the surface red?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple answer:

```
  f[x_, y_] := (1.4025 - (-0.2 + x)^2 - (-0.2 + y)^2)^0.5 + 0.15;
    Manipulate[
     Plot3D[{f[x, y], 0}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
      MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &}, Mesh -> n - 1, 
      MeshShading -> 
       ReplacePart[
        ConstantArray[Automatic, {n, n}], {Mod[m, n, 1], Ceiling[m/n]} -> 
         Red], PlotRange -> {{0, 1.6}, {-0.2, 1.4}, {0, 1.6}}, 
      BoxRatios -> Automatic], {{n, 4, "Divide quantity"}, 3, 30, 1, 
      Appearance -> "Open"}, {{m, 1, "Division number of sub region j"}, 
      1, n^2, 1, Appearance -> "Open"}]
```